# Creating azure AD app using az powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am creating an azure AD app, generating a client secret for it, and giving Reader role using az PowerShell
I want to give Microsoft Graph. Directory.readAll permission to the app, but not sure how to do using PowerShell. Can anyone help?
Here is the code I've written:

```
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId <tenant-id>
Connect-AzureAD
#Set variables for the app
$appName = "test"
$secret = "MySecret"

#Create the app
$app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -PublicClient $false

#Create the client secret
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($secret)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)
$secret = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "MyCustomKeyIdentifier" -Value $base64 -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate

#Retrieve the tenant ID
$tenantId = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId

#giving Reader Role
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -PrincipalType "ServicePrincipal"

#Print the App-ID, tenant ID, and client secret
Write-Host "App-ID: $($app.AppId)"
Write-Host "Tenant ID: $tenantId"
Write-Host "Client Secret: $($secret.Value)"
```

Comment: The following gives example in different languages of a GET.  To change settings you would use a POST.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?force_isolation=true#example-usage-36

Comment: A few things, the `AzureAD` PowerShell module will be deprecated later this year, it would be good in practice to start using the `MS Graph` module instead.

Comment: When adding API permissions to an app programmatically, the new permissions you apply will overwrite any existing permissions, therefore the new permissions you apply must also include any existing permissions.

Comment: There's a good example (using the `MS Graph` module) provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-configure-permissions?tabs=http%2Cupdatepermissions-azureadgraph-msgraph-powershell#step-2-add-azure-ad-graph-permissions-to-your-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran same PowerShell script as you and got **response** like below:

```
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId <tenantID>
Connect-AzureAD

#Set variables for the app
$appName = "test"
$secret = "MySecret"

#Create the app
$app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -PublicClient $false

#Create the client secret
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($secret)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)
$secret = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "MyCustomKeyIdentifier" -Value $base64 -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate

#Retrieve the tenant ID
$tenantId = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId

#giving Reader Role
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -PrincipalType "ServicePrincipal" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subID>/resourcegroups/<myRGname>"

#Print the App-ID, tenant ID, and client secret
Write-Host "App-ID: $($app.AppId)"
Write-Host "Tenant ID: $tenantId"
Write-Host "Client Secret: $($secret.Value)"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, application named **`test`** created successfully like below:

[image]

To add Microsoft Graph `Directory.Read.All` permission to this application, you can run below PowerShell script:

```
$Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Graph.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$DirectoryReadAll = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61","Role"
$Graph.ResourceAccess = $DirectoryReadAll
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "test" 
  
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $Graph
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **`Directory.Read.All`** permission added to the application successfully like below:

[image]

To grant **admin consent** to above permission, you need to create service principal and run PowerShell script like below:

```
$sp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AccountEnabled $true -AppId $app.AppId -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $true -DisplayName "test"
$graphsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
             -Id $DirectoryReadAll.Id `
             -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId `
             -PrincipalId $sp.ObjectId `
             -ResourceId $graphsp.ObjectId
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can check Portal where admin consent is granted successfully like below:

[image]